# Upload File with FileUpload and Stock in database using Framwork entity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, file-upload, webforms

I want to upload file with file upload and stock in DataBase SQLserver using framework entity , I use this code :

```
string strRealPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;  

    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
      {
      string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName; 
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(strRealPath + fileName);
      //Now insert the file into the database.
       }


        f.photo = Convert.ToString(FileUpload1.FileBytes);
```

But I find anything added .I use the debugger he tell me that posted file is `null`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your form should be encrypted as multipart/form-data. Add parameter to your form tag like below:

```
enctype = "multipart/form-data"
```

Secondly you have to send file as controller parameter HttpPostedFile.

[This tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38970/Implementing-HTTP-File-Upload-with-ASP-NET-MVC) will be useful for you. Let us know, does it work properly.

===EDIT===

When it comes to database. You have to have column of binary type (varbinary[max]), and you 
should try save it there (remember about try/catch). To read content of the file, use stream reader.

Comment: thnks but i use asp.net web form not mvc